# Git: Synchronize branch containing previously cherry-picked commits with master

Tags: git, workflow, git-branch

In git, what is the best / easiest way to bring a deployment branch up to date with master when the branch already contains cherry-picked commits from master, assuming you want to preserve the history of the deployment branch.

The scenario:

1. Deployment branch made off of master at some time in the past.
2. Additional commits cherry-picked from master over to deploy, leaving out some other commits.
3. Code on deploy is deployed to a production environment.
4. Now, deploy needs to be brought fully in sync with master for the next deployment.

The question is, how to do step 4 easily (avoiding any merge conflicts, since nothing unique has been committed to deploy, only cherry-picked changes) without changing any history in deploy (my understanding is that doing a rebase at this point may lose history in deploy, or make it more difficult to get the exact code that was deployed back out, but I am quite possibly mistaken in this).

Executing `git merge master` generates a number of conflicts which it would be nice to avoid since what is wanted is simply for the head of deploy to directly resemble the head of master (deploy does not contain any unique changes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question with the best method I have been able to find to do this so far.  The below command will merge master into your branch while resolving all conflicts in favor of master (run from a checkout of your branch):

```
git merge -s recursive -X theirs origin/master
```

Comment: Just did this myself, and now I'm puzzled why I got different results when merging from `origin/master`, compared to just `master` (which was up-to-date, i.e., after a pull).  On the second case, I was missing 2 code snippets.  Using `origin/master` as you suggested worked without issues and yielding the expected results.

Comment: Figured it out: I did run into a merge mismatch.  Using `--no-commit`,  I could resolve the conflict that would have happened that needed attention, everything else merged as expected.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, just merging should work fine. Git detects that the cherry-picked commits are applied already and "ignores" them during the merge. Did you try to just merge? Even if it fails you can revert easily with git and try something different (maybe another merge strategy, but I have no experience with that, yet).

If you want to rebase and still have the deployed code around, just add a tag to the code that you want to keep. The rebase will rewrite history of your commits, but the tag will still point to the code (commit) before the rebase.

Comment: Your comment on merging is a good suggestion, but it unfortunately results in a number of conflicts.  I have updated my question to indicate that for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the answer you're expecting, but it's possible you should polish your branching strategy a bit and be more granular with topic branches. That way you can merge topic branches instead of cherry-pick'ing from master. So your master branch gets all topic branches merged, and the development branch gets some topic branches merged. Then you eventually merge master on development to bring the deploy branch up to date. This isn't a guarantee you'll avoid conflicts, but it is cleaner and in the normative case will have less conflicts for you to resolve.

When you cherry-pick git loses its ability to recognise that the cherry-picked commit and the original that was cherry-pickled from are identical. This is where the conflicts come from.

Comment: I agree that is more ideal, but sometimes the situation changes and features are split up or partial versions need to be pulled in.  It is not the usual case, but it has happened, unfortunately, hence the question.